# When Multi-Classing, do you gain all class benefits?

Tags: dnd-4e

For Example:  If a Cleric multi-classes into a warlock, does the cleric gain +1 to his Will and Reflex defenses due to the warlock's "bonus to defense"?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Check out our [FAQ].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**

You only gain what the feat you used to multiclass says you gain. You also count as that class for purposes of meeting prerequisites.